# Can't install Nvidia 304 Updates on HWE 12.04.5

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, hardware-enablement-stack

I've upgraded my 12.04 LTS to the new HWE bringing the Kernel to `3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu`.

My graphics card is a Nvidia 7600 GS and needs to use `304-updates` to work. When upgrading to the new HWE the graphics driver was removed and now I'm running on the built in driver.

I can't install 304 as it gives me this error:

```
 nvidia-304-updates : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 or
                               xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                               xorg-video-abi-13 or
                               xorg-video-abi-14
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any thoughts as to what might fix my problems?

Also if I go to the Additional Drivers page it just turns up blank.

Comment: Apparently I'm not the only one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304-updates/+bug/1345217

Comment: maybe try booting into an older kernel to reinstall the driver until the bug is fixed

Comment: First time I've encountered this.  Switched to Ubuntu a few months ago. How do I boot to the older kernel?

Comment: Switched back to the older Kernel. Fixed thanks.

Comment: Upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 solved the problem for me. I must say the upgrade itself was far from straightforward. I had to uninstall `ubuntu-desktop` and `xubuntu-desktop`, then after the upgrade re-install `ubuntu-desktop` (from a root shell session, since X was crashing) and `nvidia-current`. I do not know whether this hurdle was related to the 12.04 HWE issue.

Comment: Interesting. Do you use Nvidia 304 driver's?

Comment: Yes, `nvidia-304`, both in 12.04 and (after upgrading) in 14.04. It's as if they accidentally introduced a dependency to 14.04 or some other post-Precise version when downgrading the new hardware profile to 12.04.

Comment: Weird thanks for the input. Just in the middle of a fresh install of 14.04.1

Comment: BTW can a mod close this q now? Thanks

Comment: Check out [this answer on how to install nvidia-304 after HWE update.](http://askubuntu.com/a/506403/83681)