# Hibernation error - Could not write byte: broken pipe

Tags: 12.04, boot, nvidia, hibernate, hardware-enablement-stack

Suddenly, right after "turning on" my `ubuntu 12.04` from hibernation, there was an error

> Could not write bytes:broken pipes

which led to a black screen so I had to reboot. After rebooting, I got the same error message but my screen was working fine. I hibernated again my laptop, just to check and there wasn't any error at that time, but I am experiencing something weird.

I type my password, only to see a black screen with a mouse pointer, which obbeys every movement I do. I also increased/decreased the volume and I was able to hear the sound effect.

What I did was the trying to "reinstall" nvidia drivers(my graphics card is nvidia 8600m gs) using

1. CTRL-ALT-F1 (to get a CLI)
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get purge`
4. `nvidia-* sudo apt-get install invida-current-updates`

but when I reach step 4, I get sth about dependencies on `nvidia 304` or something similar.

Any idea on why this is happening only after hibernation and how to fix it?

**EDIT** I also run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and the output is

```
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Sources                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                              
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                    
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                  
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [98.7 kB]              
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US             
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US   
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US   
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                        
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [50.7 kB]             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [854 kB]    
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [13.7 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [252 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15.5 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex      
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [442 kB]   
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [4,620 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [101 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2,650 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en         
Fetched 1,835 kB in 3min 41s (8,287 B/s)                                       
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

**EDIT 2**

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'nvidia-173-updates' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-current' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libvdpau-ia32' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cuda-debugger' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libvdpau1' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-glx-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-173' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-304' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-96-updates-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-319' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-331' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings-updates' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings-304-updates' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libopencl1' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-vdpau-driver' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-96-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-profiler' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cg-toolkit' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-96' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libvdpau1-ia32' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-173-updates-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-331-updates' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-96-updates' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-331-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-304' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-310' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'libkwinactivenvidiahack4' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-prime' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-180-modaliases' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cuda-profiler' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-current-updates' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-current-updates-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'libkwinnvidiahack4' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-opencl-icd' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libvdpau' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-304-updates-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-319-updates' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'boinc-nvidia-cuda' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-current-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-compute-profiler' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-331-uvm' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-331-updates-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-304-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings-304' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings-319' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-va-driver' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-current-modaliases' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-173-modaliases' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-185-modaliases' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-319-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-texture-tools' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-304-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-common' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-tegra' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings-319-updates' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-331-updates-uvm' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cuda-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cuda-doc' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cuda-gdb' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-304-updates' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-experimental-310-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cuda-toolkit' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-libvdpau-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'libgl1-nvidia-alternatives' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-96-modaliases' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-glx' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings-experimental-304' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings-experimental-310' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-173-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-319-updates-dev' for regex 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'libnvtt-bin' instead of 'nvidia-texture-tools'
Note, selecting 'vdpau-va-driver' instead of 'nvidia-va-driver'
Package nvidia-96-updates is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-96-updates-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-cg-toolkit is not installed, so not removed
Package libkwinactivenvidiahack4 is not installed, so not removed
Package libkwinnvidiahack4 is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-common is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-prime is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-settings is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-settings-304 is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-settings-304-updates is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-settings-319 is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-settings-319-updates is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-settings-experimental-304 is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-settings-experimental-310 is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-173 is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-173-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-173-updates is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-173-updates-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-304 is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-304-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-304-updates is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-304-updates-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-319 is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-319-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-319-updates is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-319-updates-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-331 is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-331-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-331-updates is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-331-updates-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-331-updates-uvm is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-331-uvm is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-96 is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-96-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-current is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-current-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-current-updates is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-current-updates-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-experimental-304 is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-experimental-304-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-experimental-310 is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-experimental-310-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-settings-updates is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-compute-profiler is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-cuda-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-cuda-doc is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-cuda-gdb is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-cuda-toolkit is not installed, so not removed
Package nvidia-opencl-dev is not installed, so not removed
Package boinc-nvidia-cuda is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-gfs-gazis latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp thunderbird-globalmenu
  ttf-gfs-neohellenic ttf-gfs-didot-classic ttf-gfs-baskerville
  ttf-sil-gentium ttf-gfs-didot gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 linux-headers-3.2.0-52
  fonts-gfs-theokritos linux-headers-3.2.0-52-generic-pae fonts-gfs-didot
  fonts-gfs-solomos preview-latex-style latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp
  ruby1.8 fonts-gfs-olga ttf-gfs-bodoni-classic ruby ttf-gfs-olga
  libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 ttf-gfs-porson dkms fonts-gfs-didot-classic
  ttf-gfs-artemisia ttf-gfs-solomos fonts-gfs-porson linux-headers-3.5.0-23
  fonts-gfs-neohellenic fonts-gfs-artemisia fonts-gfs-bodoni-classic
  fonts-gfs-baskerville screen-resolution-extra lcdf-typetools libvdpau1
  latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp ttf-gfs-gazis libkms1 libruby1.8 tex-gyre
  swath ko.tex-extra-hlfont ttf-gfs-theokritos linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic
  libreadline5 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp pfb2t1c2pfb openjdk-7-jre-lib
  texinfo
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


sudo apt-get install nvidia-current


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-current : Depends: nvidia-304 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

sudo apt-get install nvidia-304


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-304 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 or
                       xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-13 or
                       xorg-video-abi-14
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I installed `xorg-video-abi-11`, later `nvidia-304` and then `nvidia-current`

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and post the output in to your question

Comment: @bain : Thank you very much for your comment! I've just edited my question.

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` and post the output in to your question

Comment: That is [bug #1345217 - nvidia-304-update (video driver) got uninstalled and is uninstallable after update to HWE-Stack5 (from Ubuntu LTS 12.04.4 to 12.04.5)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304-updates/+bug/1345217)

Comment: possible duplicate of [12.04.x HWE Hardware Enablement Update broke Nvidia proprietary drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/503724/12-04-x-hwe-hardware-enablement-update-broke-nvidia-proprietary-drivers)

Comment: Check the duplicate question for a potential fix.

Comment: @bain : This really fixed it! Would you mind posting it as an answer, so that I can accept it? Thank you very much for you help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [bug #1345217 - *"nvidia-304-update (video driver) got uninstalled and is uninstallable after update to HWE-Stack5 (from Ubuntu LTS 12.04.4 to 12.04.5)"*](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304-updates/+bug/1345217) and can be fixed by following the instructions in [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503724/12-04-x-hwe-hardware-enablement-update-broke-nvidia-proprietary-drivers#506403)