# X doesn't start anymore on 12.04 LTS after HWE upgrade

Tags: 12.04, xorg

12.04 LTS asked me to upgrade my "HWE" since the current one was no longer supported. I performed HWE upgrade and now Ubuntu comes up with a black screen and doesn't start.

Using the "Recovery" boot from the advanced boot options, I have already performed fix for broken packages, which turned up nothing. When I try to start "failsafeX" I get the following error:

```
gdm: unrecognized service
stop: Unknown instance:
xinit /usr/share/xdiagnose/failsafeXinit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe with - -- /u
sr/bin/X  -br -once -config /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe -logfile /var/log/Xorg.f
ailsafe.log

X: cannot stat /etx/X11/X (No such file or directory), aborting.
```

My computer has an nVidia GTX580 graphics card and I have been using the nVidia proprietary driver prior to the HWE upgrade.

Comment: Does [this article](http://askubuntu.com/q/503724/39753) apply to you?

Comment: That article was somewhat helpful. Un-installing nvidia and re-installing xorg and lightdm got me a working desktop again. There I installed the linux-header package and re-installed the nVidia driver. All is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Using recovery, Enable networking so that *your disks may mount in rw mode* , then **Drop to root Shell.**

In this terminal enter the following commands - **one at a time per line:**

Code:

```
sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get upgrade 

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get -f install 

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

**Now reboot**

Code:

```
 sudo shutdown -r now
```